# How would I find the cost of a neural network without knowing the target output like for a game?

Tags: neural-network

For example,

I want to create an AI that plays Ticktacktoe, this is how I would go about it.
I have 9 input nodes which is for each space on the board, 3 nodes for one hidden layer (which I'm guessing would somehow benefit the AI by having it select a row or column with 3 spaces), and then 9 output nodes to see where the AI would put its mark on the entire board.

I'm lost on how I would find the cost of this neural network because I don't know how I would judge its prediction and affect its weights and biases.
If I wanted the AI to play a guessing game, it would make sense since I have the correct answer and I can teach it to be more accurate based on how off it was to the actual answer.

(NOTE: I am very new to neural networks, so there may be a simple answer that I've missed somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did some digging around and found a good introduction to reinforcement learning. This is the method that is used to train neural networks to achieve a goal without knowing an exact target like which move is good in a certain scenario. Backpropagation is not the only learning method, but so many sources only used this method without letting the viewer know of any other methods which confused me.

Going through this playlist right now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pWv7GOvuf0&index=1&list=PL7-jPKtc4r78-wCZcQn5IqyuWhBZ8fOxT

Hope this will help someone getting started with neural networks!